# Createrawtransaction - rpc connection bitcoind

Tags: java, json, rpc, bitcoind

when I'm trying to prepare and send an rpc request to my bitcoin-qt wallet via JSONRPC2 connection I don't get anyresponse (String is empty). When I put command into bitcoin-qt konsole is working fine. Here my code.

```
String requestBody = "{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\""+method+"\""+tmpS+",\"id\":9}";
```

and JSON object sending to client :

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"createrawtransaction","params":"[[{"txid":"ba9b655fc17448a422ae9afd28ed264a91fa631c3d131468d674bc2cf7757a3e","vout":0},{"txid":"66672599375caa1fee0d59562531b3cb57da35554ff666e34e53c06c3f1c9415","vout":1}]","{"mgGWs59KnzSt6vpA5zm1EkP2xDzYe58hHF":4.78396431}"]","id":9}
```

With commands like `listunspent` or `getaccountaddress` everything working good. Maybe the error is on the "multiple params" side.

Thanks, for help.